# refreshing map ItemizedOverlay gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-maps, itemizedoverlay

Using the com.google.android.maps API, I've got a `MapActivity` which uses `ItemizedOverlay` to place several (up to about 1000) icons on a `MapView`.  I want to refresh (or perhaps just add to the list of) the icons when the `LocationListener` detects the device has moved a certain distance (currently 5 meters, but that's just for testing).

I've added [`setLastFocusedIndex(-1)`](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/android-itemizedoverlay-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-nullpointerexception-workarounds/) and [`populate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755921/problem-with-crash-with-itemizedoverlay), but my ItemizedOverlay is still crashing.  <del>I think it's crashing when I add more items to the list, but sometimes it seems to crash even if I don't move my phone.</del> It crashes on the first update.  I can't tell from LogCat exactly what's triggering the error.

My MapActivity is based off various tutorials:

**EDIT**: tweaked code to do a [batch update of items](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1943680#1943680) but it still crashes

```
public class NearbyActivity extends MapActivity implements VenueCatalogListener {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private int latE6;
    private int lonE6;

    private Location current_location;
    private VenuesFromServer venues_from_server;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        venues_from_server = new VenuesFromServer(this);
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        setContentView(R.layout.nearby_view);


        RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapMainLayout);

        mapView = new MapView(this, PreferencesManager.CLUBBERIA_MAPS_API_KEY);
        initializeMap();

        linearLayout.addView(mapView);
    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        mapView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(mapView.getMaxZoomLevel()-5); // Zoom 1 is world view

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        if(itemizedOverlay == null) {
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(current_location == null) {
                current_location = location;
            }

            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
            if(current_location.distanceTo(location) > 5) {
                // this kicks off an async task that will call back to venueListUpdated() below
                venues_from_server.getVenueJSONFromServer(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 19);
            }
            mapController.animateTo(point); //  mapController.setCenter(point);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void venueListUpdated() {

        // Base.B.arrayVenuesMap is an ArrayList<Venue>
        for(int i=0;i<Base.B.arrayVenuesMap.size();i++) {
            Venue _venue = Base.B.arrayVenuesMap.get(i);
            latE6 =  (int) (_venue.latitude*1e6);
            lonE6 = (int) (_venue.longitude*1e6);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latE6, lonE6);
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, _venue.name, "");
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem, drawable);
        }
        itemizedOverlay.batchPopulate();
    }
}
```

My ItemizedOverlay looks like this:

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = null;

    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay, Drawable defaultMarker) {
        if(!mOverlays.contains(overlay)) {
            setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
            overlay.setMarker(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            mOverlays.add(overlay);
        }
    }

    public void batchPopulate() {
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }
}
```

Logcat features the following lines:

```
11-24 18:28:02.245: D/AsyncJSONClient(18382): starting connect with this many pairs: 0; thread 17
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getIndexToDraw(ItemizedOverlay.java:211)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.draw(ItemizedOverlay.java:240)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6918)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6921)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6921)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6921)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1947)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1539)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1275)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1876)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3728)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
11-24 18:28:02.255: E/AndroidRuntime(18382):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 18:28:02.255: W/ActivityManager(308):   Force finishing activity com.clubberia.android/.ClubberiaMain
```

How can I occasionally add items to ItemizedOverlay without crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ni know its a bit old, but @cgwylie is almost right..

you should call `populate()` after updating overlays values... and then you can call the `postInvalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

When you change items in an `ItemizedOverlay`, you need to call `postInvalidate()` on your `MapView` to let it know you've adjusted the overlays so it won't try and draw items that aren't in the list again.

In your `venueListUpdated()` you may try adding `mapView.postInvalidate()` after calling `itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem, drawable)` to resolve your problem.

Comment: hmm.   I just tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Cool, sorry it didn't work, it's solved the problem in the past for me.