# Extended OverlayItem causes program to crash with NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, itemizedoverlay

I have a class which extends OverlayItem to include more fields. I have changed all the OverlayItem occurrences in my program with a PointOfInterest class.

When I try to run the same program which worked for OverlayItem, it crashes with a nullpointerException after calling **populate()** in my ItemizedOverlay class. The Log prints out the correct value. Here is the method it crashes in.

```
protected void addOverlay(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest) {

    mapOverlays.add(pointOfInterest);
    setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
    Log.d("Add Overlay", pointOfInterest.getDescription());
    populate(); <-- Crashes here
}
```

And the error

```
12-06 17:29:03.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1822): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 17:29:03.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate(ItemizedOverlay.java:312)
12-06 17:29:03.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at com.example.mapproject.OurItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(OurItemizedOverlay.java:108)
12-06 17:29:03.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at com.example.mapproject.MainActivity.addPointToMap(MainActivity.java:211)
```

Any ideas? Thanks !

Comment: The error is at line number 312 so you tell which thing is null at line number 312?

Comment: I don't have access to that class, I extend ItemizedOverlay to OurItemizedOverlay

Comment: Can you call `populate()` before you call `setLastFocuedIndex(-1)` and report back please?

Comment: There is a similar question.. Maybe this helps you: 
Problem with crash with ItemizedOverlay
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755921/problem-with-crash-with-itemizedoverlay

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks like that was a bug that has been fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I failed to mention that the PointOfInterest being passed to the addOverlay method was created from a JSON String, therefore the constructor which contains

```
super(point, title, snippet)
```

was never being called.

I added this to my the addOverlay method which seems to have sorted it !

```
protected void addOverlay(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest) {

    PointOfInterest pointOfInterest2 = new PointOfInterest(pointOfInterest.title,pointOfInterest.title,pointOfInterest.type,pointOfInterest.point,pointOfInterest.privateField);
    mapOverlays.add(pointOfInterest2);
    setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
    Log.d("Add Overlay", pointOfInterest2.getSnippet());
    populate();

}
```