# Google maps android api v1 mapview tutorial crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing the MapView tutorial found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

The problem is that it keeps crashing. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.googlemapstest;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

    drawable.setBounds(0,0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    overlayitem.setMarker(drawable); 

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem, drawable);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And the HelloItemizedOverlay class:

```
package com.example.googlemapstest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay
{
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays;
Context mContext; 

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      mOverlays =  new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(); 
      populate(); 
    }

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay, Drawable drawable) {
    overlay.setMarker(drawable); 
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
public int size() {
  return mOverlays.size();
}

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      mContext = context;
      mOverlays =  new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(); 
      populate(); 
    }

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

The exception I keep getting is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapstest/com.example.googlemapstest.MainActivity} : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The crash happens at the populate() line in  itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem, drawable);
Now, initially I found that the mMarker variable of the OverlayItem I was adding was null, and added two lines to manually set it. However, the program still kept crashing!

I then found this question: [Problem with crash with ItemizedOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755921/problem-with-crash-with-itemizedoverlay) which seemed to be dealing with the same error.

I did as recommended in the best answer there, but still no luck.

I believe I've vigourously combed this, and can't imagine where the null error is coming from. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using v1 of Maps rather than v2? You'll get much more help going forward if you are using a non-deprecated library.

Comment: I am starting to maintain a api v1 application, and am doing the tutorial to get to grips with the basic concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be returning `null` in `createItem(int index)`, meaning you should change the following method in your `HelloItemizedOverlay` class:

```
@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

The most basic implementation should return the `OverlayItem` object appropriate for the given `index`. Quite probably, you'll just want to return whatever object is located in the list of `OverlayItem`s at the same index. For example:

```
@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
    return mOverlays.get(index);
}
```

That will only make sense if you also populate that list somewhere. Also, to avoid confusion, you should probably rename the variable to `mOverlayItems`, since that is what it contains (as opposed to 'overlays').

More importantly, as @ianhanniballake already mentioned: the Android Maps SDK v1 has been deprecated in favour of v2. This means that from **March 3rd, 2013** you will no longer be able to request an API key for v1. Better hurry up and generate a key now, if you haven't done so yet, or just migrate to v2 now, which probably wouldn't be a bad move.

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you so much. That was so obvious it was a little embarrassing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012

Go with Google Map API V2 and make your life easy

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Happy coding

Comment: I do realize this, unfortunately for several reasons I need to use api v1.